# Как передать аргумент в функцию, в качестве атрибута класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь передать аргумент в функцию, чтобы этот аргумент был вызван классом. Но данный код вызывает ошибку: AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'value'. Не очень хорошо знаком с классами, подскажите как можно это реализовать.

```
class Test:
        account_number = 1
        number_messages = 100
        number_groups = 5

def some_function(value: str):
    Test.value


some_function("account_number")
```

AttributeError: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'value'

Comment: А где сам `Report`-то объявлен? Что это за синтаксис?

Comment: Как заставить ЧТО работать? Что тут должно происходить? Что такое Report?

Comment: Я подправил вопрос, надеюсь сейчас стало понятнее.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы получить атрибут класса или же его метод, по переданной строке нужно использовать функцию getattr, в таком случае, ваш код будет выглядеть вот так:

```
class Test:
    account_number = 1
    number_messages = 100
    number_groups = 5


def some_function(value: str):
    return getattr(Test, value)


print(some_function("account_number"))
```

Вывод

```
1
```

Comment: Благодарю, я как раз только что нашел ответ. Спасибо ещё раз))

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Необходимо вызвать функцию getattr и передать в неё первым аргументом класс (экземпляр класса), а вторым атрибут.

```
class Test:
    account_number = 1
    number_messages = 100
    number_groups = 5


def some_function(value: str):
    print(getattr(Test, value))


some_function("account_number")
```

Output: 1

Comment: Только в данном виде код даёт ту же самую ошибку

Comment: Благодарю за комментарий, код подправил